# Install pygeoprocessing on ubuntu 14.04 and python3

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the pygeoprocessing package for Python 3.4 on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I have all the necessary versions of the required dependencies (GDAL, numpy, scipy, shapely, Cython). pygeoprocessing is successfully installed via pip. However, when I try to import it in to a python script, I am greeted with the following:

`File "route.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygeoprocessing import routing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygeoprocessing/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygeoprocessing.geoprocessing as geoprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygeoprocessing/geoprocessing.py", line 13, in <module>
    import exceptions
ImportError: No module named 'exceptions'`

I cannot remove this line in the source code because I do not have write access on the VM. exceptions is presumably an artifact of the python2 release, and doesn't exist in python3.

How do I build pygeoprocessing properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (without modifying the code) as the exceptions module was removed in python 3.  Note: the package metadata specifies [Python 2 only](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoprocessing):

`Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only`

I suggest you raise an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/richpsharp/pygeoprocessing/issues) requesting a port to Python 3.

You could try downloading, modifying and building the [code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoprocessing) yourself, then installing without root to your user site directory: `python3 setup.py install --user`

The *minimum* you'll need to do is modify `pygeoprocessing/geoprocessing.py` and delete line 13 and change line 2177 from `raise exceptions.IOError(error_message)` to `raise IOError(error_message)` (this change won't break Python 2 as importing `exceptions` to raise an `IOError` is unnecessary). Note that you may come across other Python 2->3 porting issues which are off topic here on GIS StackExchange.